# Who decides 'requires additional references', moderators or system?

Tags: support, sources-and-citations, post-quality

I am getting this message in one of my answer:

"Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted."

But I have provided proper reference, is it necessary to provide a URL link?

Comment: Visit [Official policy for deleting answers that don't cite sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/277)

Comment: Policy seems ok...but I believe there is a bug in posting this warning message by system...

Comment: Those post notices are not added automatically by system. It's added by moderators.

Comment: But moderator's name not appearing there...and I don't think that proper references r not there in my answer...but no issue if human intervention is there...I thought some machine learning algorithm is there so just wanted to confirm..Thank you :)

Comment: "But I have provided proper reference, is it necessary to provide a URL link?"@YDS   There's no need to provide online link, you can mention name of chapter, verse numbers and scriptures name or just chapter name if you summarizing the content .If you think your answer has proper references or after adding references, you can flag mods to remove "post notices"

Comment: @YDS Take a look at [various post notices](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/746/277).

Comment: There's no bug in it. It was added by a moderator. You didn't link to proper post. There wasn't any error there.

Comment: "But I have provided proper reference" Provide link to your answer post to investigate.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22231/how-to-please-lord-shiva-to-get-grace/22469#22469

Comment: @YDS It doesn't require post notice. let me remove it.

Comment: @YDS Next time, if you think your answer has proper references, flag it directly to mods. flag --> "in need of moderator attention" and "post your message,"

Comment: @TheDestroyer will do... thank you!

Comment: @TheDestroyer The sources were added after the notice. Before that, the user didn't cite those sources explicitly in the answer. He just said they are related. I believe that was the reason for the banner. Now also, they are not posted as sources, it just says questions are related. Also they are not linked to answers. It's linked to the question.

Comment: @YDS Yes, I'm the one who added the post notice.  At the time your post wasn't backed up with sources.  Now it is, so the post notice is no longer needed.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan but after notice I immediately added one comment but still notice was there then I added sources and still notice was there...so just wanted to confirm the process...now I understood that after editing we have to flag it to Moderators so that they can remove that notice.. thanks!